# Firebase Auth Revoke Token not Working in SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I have a SwiftUI app in Xcode 14.3 targeting iOS 16+ using the Firebase 10.9.0 SDK. I'm using Sign In with Apple successfully to allow the user to sign in and out of Firebase. Now I'm trying to add the capability for users to delete their accounts. When doing so, the auth token must be revoked. I'm calling `Auth.auth().revokeToken`, but it throws an error stating "Code flow is not enabled for Apple."

How do I enable code flow for an iOS app written in SwiftUI? The Firebase docs are not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to follow all the steps in the [Configure Sign in with Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#configure_sign_in_with_apple) section. In addition to enabling the authentication provider, you also need fill out the *Services ID* and *OAuth code flow configuration*. The documentation explains how to do this.

Comment: Got it working. I must say, the docs, especially from Apple, are not the best.

Comment: @JeffG it is a complicated process, and if you’ve got any suggestions for how to improve the docs, I’d be happy to hear them (ping me on Twitter)